# azure deploy error "Changing Availability Set SKU from 'Aligned' to 'Classic' is not allowed."

Tags: powershell, azure

When I try to deploy to azure using powershell with a template, I am getting this error: "Changing Availability Set SKU from 'Aligned' to 'Classic' is not allowed."

This is my template file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.2",
  "parameters": {
    "tagvalues": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "Owner": "Fill in",
        "environment": "Fill in",
        "Engagement": "Fill in",
        "Role": "Fill in",
        "LOB": "Fill in",
        "Application": "Fill in"
      }
    },
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
        "description": "This is the name of the your VM"
      }
    },
     "imageName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "This is the name of the image file. Must end in .vhd"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network Name"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet Name"
      }
    },
    "existingVnetResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource Group Name for Vnet"
      }
    },
    "osStorageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_A2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "This is the size of your VM"
      }
    },
     "avSetName": {
      "type":"string",
       "metadata":{
        "description": "Availability Set Name" 
       }
    },
    "adminUserName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "smadmin"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "vmName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
    "nicName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-Nic')]",
    "osDiskVhdUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('osStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', parameters('vmName'),'-osDisk.vhd')]",
    "hostName": "[toLower(concat(parameters('vmName'), '.nix.us.company_world.company.com'))]",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "imageUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('osStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/images/',parameters('imageName'))]"
   },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
      "tags": {
        "Owner": "[parameters('tagvalues').Owner]",
        "environment": "[parameters('tagvalues').environment]",
        "Engagement": "[parameters('tagvalues').Engagement]",
        "Name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
        "Role": "[parameters('tagvalues').Role]",
        "LOB": "[parameters('tagvalues').LOB]",
        "Application": "[parameters('tagvalues').Application]"
        },
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
               "subnet": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId(parameters('existingVnetResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName')), '/subnets/',parameters('subnetName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('avSetName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "properties": {
        "managed": "false",
        "platformFaultDomainCount":3,
        "platformUpdateDomainCount":3
      },
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "Owner": "[parameters('tagvalues').Owner]",
        "environment": "[parameters('tagvalues').environment]",
        "Engagement": "[parameters('tagvalues').Engagement]",
        "Role": "[parameters('tagvalues').Role]",
        "LOB": "[parameters('tagvalues').LOB]",
        "Application": "[parameters('tagvalues').Application]"
            }
      },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
      "tags": {
        "Owner": "[parameters('tagvalues').Owner]",
        "environment": "[parameters('tagvalues').environment]",
        "Engagement": "[parameters('tagvalues').Engagement]",
        "Role": "[parameters('tagvalues').Role]",
        "LOB": "[parameters('tagvalues').LOB]",
        "Application": "[parameters('tagvalues').Application]"
    },  
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', parameters('avsetName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('hostName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-osDisk')]",
            "osType": "[variables('osType')]",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
             "caching": "ReadWrite",
             "image": {
                "uri": "[variables('imageUri')]"
            }, 
             "vhd": {
                "uri": "[variables('osDiskVhdUri')]"
            }
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": false
            }
        },
         "availabilitySet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',parameters('avSetName'))]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "ipAddress": {
        "value": "[reference(variables('nicName')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]",
        "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my parameters file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.2",
  "parameters": {
    "tagvalues": {
      "value": {
        "Owner": "That Guy",
        "environment": "Production",
        "Engagement": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "Role": "Proxy",
        "LOB": "Advisory",
        "Application": "company Leasing Tool"
      }
    },
      "vmName": {
      "value": "machine_name"
    },
     "osStorageAccountName": {
      "value": "vm_storage2"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "vnet-prod-core1"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "value": "vnet-prod-core1-subnet-perimeter"
    },
    "existingVnetResourceGroupName": {
      "value": "rg-core1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The resource group where the VNET is located."
      }
    },
    "imageName": {
      "value": "image-rhel-72-20170418.vhd",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Enter the name of the image."
      }
    },
     "vmSize": {
      "value": "Standard_D1"
    },
    "avSetName": {
      "value": "avset-proxy2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of availability set to add this VM. If it doesn't exist, it will be created."
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "mysadmin"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "value": "secret"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the powershell that I'm using to try and launch the machine:

```
 Login-AzureRmAccount

select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Asset.Prod"

$folder = "C:\Users\mysuer\Desktop\important_folders\Projects\repo\MS-Azure-Cloud\Templates\VirtualMachines\LinuxImageAvSet\" #Must end in trailing slash.
$rg = "rg-shared"
$template = "azuredeploy_unmanaged.json"
$param = "LinuxDeploymentsParameters/machine_name.params.json"
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rg -TemplateFile ($folder + $template) -TemplateParameterFile ($folder + $param) -Verbose
```

This is the full output of the error that I'm getting:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 1:02:41 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets 'avset--proxy2' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "OperationNotAllowed",
    "message": "Changing Availability Set SKU from 'Aligned' to 'Classic' is not allowed."
  }
}'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rg -TemplateFi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

VERBOSE: 1:02:41 PM - Resource Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'machine_name-Nic' provisioning status is succeeded
VERBOSE: 1:02:41 PM - Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 1:02:46 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for 
usage details.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rg -TemplateFi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 1:02:46 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for 
usage details.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rg -TemplateFi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

My files are on the right paths:

```
ls -lh C:\Users\myser\Desktop\important_folders\Projects\repo\MS-Azure-Cloud\Templates\VirtualMachines\KTECHLinuxImageAvSet\azuredeploy_unmanaged.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 myser 1049089 6.0K Jun  9 13:02 'C:\Users\myser\Desktop\important_folders\Projects\repo\MS-Azure-Cloud\Templates\VirtualMachines\KTECHLinuxImageAvSet\azuredeploy_unmanaged.json'

 ls C:\Users\myser\Desktop\important_folders\Projects\repo\MS-Azure-Cloud\Templates\VirtualMachines\company_tech_avset\LinuxDeploymentsParameters\machine_name.params.json
'C:\Users\myser\Desktop\important_folders\Projects\repo\MS-Azure-Cloud\Templates\VirtualMachines\company_tech_avset\LinuxDeploymentsParameters\machine_name.params.json'
```

How can I correct this and get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the root cause is that, the availability sets work for Virtual Machine Managed Disks and Unmanaged Disk now.
Below is the new script, and we can find only **two** additional lines of code "sku" and the "name": "**Aligned**" or "name": "**classic**":

```
{
"name": "[Parameters('availabilitySetName')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
"apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
"sku": {
"name": "Classic"
},
"tags": {
},
"properties": {
"platformUpdateDomainCount": 1,
"platformFaultDomainCount": 1
}
},
```

Managed Disk VM use Aligned, unmanaged disk use classic. more information please refer to this [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability).

Comment: Does it work now? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.